# Нет designer.exe в папке pyqt5-tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, python-3.8

Я в консоли написал команду: `pip3 install PyQt5`.
У меня установился `PyQt`, но я не могу найти там `designer.exe`. Я уже просмотрел много форумов, где нужно было установить `pyqt5-tools`, и всем им это помогало, но мне не помог. (папка `pyqt5-tools`)[image: Это мои файлы в папке pyqt5-tools]. У меня есть только эти 4 папки и 3 файла. Я там не нашёл `designer.exe`, пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: Удалите PyQt5 потом pyqt5-tools

Comment: Если остались какие то файлы от PyQt5 или pyqt5-tools удалите вручную

Comment: потом pip install pyqt5-tools

Comment: @Александр не получилось всё равно найти `designer.exe`

Comment: [Вот.](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Скачать Qt Designer](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download)

Не знаю, чем вызвана у вас проблема, но можно скачать его отдельно. На маке это по сути было лучшее решение, как насчет винды не знаю, но это кажется удобным.

Answer (score 0):

Вот моя последовательность действий по добыче "designer" сносим все лишние питоны
устанавливаем 3.9 (3.10 не совместим с тулсом).
pip install pyqt5 (смотрим что установилось все без ошибок)
pip install pyqt5-tools (смотрим что установилось все без ошибок если что проверяем что питон 3.9)
у меня файл designer.exe так и не появился (зато появился qt5-tools)
даем командную строку
**qt5-tools designer**
(можно создать ярлык на файл qt5-tools и дописать в него designer)